# How to navigate in jquery Mobile from one html page to other?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova

How can i navigate from one HTML page to other HTML page using Mobile jQuery?
I tried this one:

```
 function temperature()
{
  $.mobile.changePage("temperature.html",{reloadPage:true});
}
```

when i clicked on temperature button temperature function is called.

```
   <button id="TempConvert" data-theme="b" onClick="temperature()">Temprature Converter</button>
```

i got error message  Error while Loading Page.

I used below scripts tags to include `.js` files

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />     
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery-1.7.2.min"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

`

Comment: You're using an obsolete version of jQM, use latest one 1.4.5.

Comment: Have a read at http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/navigation/

Answer (score 0):

You could use an anchor:  `<a href="temperature.html" data-role="button">Go temp!</a>`  and style it so it looks like a button (that is what the data-role="button" part does).
The anchor will still behave like a regular anchor but it will look like a button.